# How to GPU accelerate CSS transform?

Tags: css, animation, transform, gpu

I know that sometimes browsers will GPU accelerate a CSS transform. But when does that happen, and is there a way to force GPU acceleration for a smooth animation?

[this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most modern browsers support GPU acceleration, but they only use it when they think a DOM element will benefit from it. The strongest indication is that a 3D transformation is being applied. So use the 3D-equivalent transform. For example, instead of `transform: translateX(50px)`, use `transform: translate3d(50px, 0, 0)`. See [this article](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the css "will-change" property:

```
will-change: transform;
```

Some css properties which are GPU accelerated (not always):

- filter
- opacity
- transform