# what i have to change in css classes properites so that make most use of GPU

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have single page Angular based web application.And using below css classes for styling.
so what i need to do in these below css classes so that most make use of GPU instead of using CPU.
Like
transform,transition,position etc etc.

here is the css style scss file.
**CSS:**

```
.tree-children.tree-children-no-padding { padding-left: 0 }
.tree-children { padding-left: 20px; overflow: hidden }
.node-drop-slot { display: block; height: inherit }
.node-drop-slot.is-dragging-over { background: #ddffee; height: 20px; border: 2px dotted #888; }
.toggle-children-wrapper-expanded .toggle-children { transform: rotate(90deg) }
.toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed .toggle-children { transform: rotate(0); }
.toggle-children-wrapper {
  padding: 2px 3px 5px 1px;
}

.toggle-children {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  height: 8px;
  width: 9px;
  background-size: contain;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -.65px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.toggle-children-placeholder {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
.node-content-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: background-color .15s,box-shadow .15s;
}
.node-wrapper {display: flex; align-items: flex-start;}
.node-content-wrapper-active,

.node-content-wrapper-focused { background: #e7f4f9 }


.node-content-wrapper.is-dragging-over { background: #ddffee; box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #999; }
.node-content-wrapper.is-dragging-over-disabled { opacity: 0.5 }

tree-viewport {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  min-width: 170px;
}

tree-viewport {
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tree-children { padding-left: 20px }
.empty-tree-drop-slot .node-drop-slot { height: 20px; min-width: 100px }

.angular-tree-component {
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* non-prefixed version, currently not supported by any browser */
}

tree-root .angular-tree-component-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
tree-root .angular-tree-component-rtl .toggle-children-wrapper-collapsed .toggle-children {
  transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
}
tree-root .angular-tree-component-rtl .tree-children {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
}

tree-node-checkbox {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

And functionality also work as usual.

Please any help.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to GPU accelerate CSS transform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32614455/how-to-gpu-accelerate-css-transform)

Comment: @Greedo similar but little different Actually i am looking for like `transform: rotate(90deg)` equivalent ? etc etc to accelarate on gpu

Comment: As said in the answer you can use `will-change: transform` and `translate3D`, but it's not something sure (depends from browser implementation and system)

Comment: That's ok depend on browser but in above example where to apply and how...looking sample example.

Comment: use `will-change: transform` and `rotate3D` instead of `rotate`

Comment: so rotate3D will perform functioning same whatever doing by rotate?...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217085/discussion-between-r08-and-greedo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use mostly `transform` for better performance.

Also make sure you add `will-change: transform` to your element, which will have transform property.

Also it will be good to add `contain: layout` to inform browser that what happens inside that box will not affect other part of page and vise versa. This would allow browser to make optimisations for that specific module / box / div.

Comment: please little bit more description and can u if possible plz edit in above my css classes...And also if contains:layout what if other module/box like dynamically resizing...any side effect?

Comment: what is the replacement for transition and position properties?

Comment: Using position is not a problem, but you should try to avoid changing `top, left, right, bottom`. Instead you should use `transform:translateY(10px)` for example, especially if you are doing animations.

Idea of using `contain: layout` is following - if you have parent which contain the animation and elements that are changable, you can add `contain` property to it.
It should not have any side effects.

Anyway for contain you may search and read a bit more and you will get the point.